# python script to decipher a message

Tags: python

Hello so I have to write a python script that will decipher the following text:

```
text="g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb."
```

using the conversion that each letter is the letter 2 ahead of it in the alphabet, so K is M, O is Q, E is G etc.

I tried to write a script myself but I am completely new to program so I do not know how to proceed from here, can anyone help?

```py
text="g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb."

def decipher_message(text):
    for letter in text: 
        new_text=text.replace(letter, chr(ord(letter)+2))
        return(new_text) 
decipher_message(text)
```

(i put indentations in my script, im not sure why they are not showing up here)

my program only changes the first letter "g", and all other g's into an "i". how do i get it to do it for all the letters and not just "g"?

Answer (score 0):

```
def decipher_message(text):
  new_text = ''
  for letter in text: 
    new_text += chr(ord(letter)+2)
  return(new_text)
```

Your code as written has the following issues.

1. your return is inside your function and therefore after a single iteration it ends.
2. When you take the original string, you do a replace and assign it to a new value. So every time through the loop you'll replace the old value. i.e. BOO -> DOO -> BNN. Because it always starts from the original string and does 1 replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the ord/chr pattern you could just do this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
text="g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb."

result = []

for c in text:
    if (index := ascii_lowercase.find(c)) >= 0:
        result.append(ascii_lowercase[(index+2)%len(ascii_lowercase)])
    else:
        result.append(c)

print(''.join(result))
```

**Output:**

```
i hope you didnt transate it by hand. thats what computers are for. doing it in by hand is inefficient and that's why this text is so long. using string.maketrans() is recommended.
```